# jQuery AJAX Progress Bar Gets Stuck if using AjaxSubmit, won't work at all without it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

First off - apologies in advance if I'm missing something obvious, I've looked all around and just can't get my head around this one!

I have an upload form that provides a progress bar, it's based on this tutorial: http://chemicaloliver.net/programming/php-5-4-file-upload-progress-and-html5-progress-bars/

Except I am trying to have the progress bar display in a lightbox using this jQuery plugin: http://s3.envato.com/files/1099520/index.html#help20

The progress bar appears but gets stuck at 18% (bytes processed: 921420) - **irrespective of the filesize being uploaded** (which doesn't make any sense to me).
I've checked PHPINFO and it shows:

**upload_max_filesize:** 4096K

**post_max_size:** 4096K

If I remove the **$('#fileUpload').ajaxSubmit(); e.preventDefault();** lines then everything then the progress bar appears, the interval is called repeatedly but the getJSON never gets called to the progress bar is not updated.  The file uploads perfectly however.

The javascript is:

```
<script>
var interval_id = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
        //jquery form options
        var options = {success: stopProgress, error: stopProgress};

        //Add the submit handler to the form
        $('#fileUpload').submit(function(e){
                if($('#selectedFile').val() == ''){alert('File Not Found'); e.preventDefault();return;}//check there is at least one file

                    var html = $('<h2>Progress</h2><div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="progress-bar progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" id="progress"><span class="sr-only">50% Complete (success)</span>  </div></div><p id="progress-txt"></p>');

                    $.lightbox(html, {width   : 350,height  : 150});

                interval_id = setInterval(function() {                      //Poll the server for progress
                        $.getJSON('progress.php', function(data){
                                if(data){                                       //if there is some progress then update the status
                                        $('#progress').width((data.bytes_processed / data.content_length) * 100 + '%');
                                        $('#progress-txt').html('Uploading '+ Math.round((data.bytes_processed / data.content_length)*100) + '%');
                                }else{//When there is no data the upload is complete
                                        $('#progress').width('100%');
                                        $('#progress-txt').html('Complete');
                                        stopProgress();
                                }
                            })}, 300);

                $('#fileUpload').ajaxSubmit(); 
                e.preventDefault();
        }); 
});

function stopProgress(){clearInterval(interval_id);}
</script>
```

The HTML Form is:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal col-md-12" id="fileUpload">
<input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="Select File" name="selectedFile" id="selectedFile" required />
<button type="submit">Save This Download</button>
</form
```

Comment: What I would love to able to do is have the progress bar working without the use of 'ajaxsubmit' and 'preventDefault' so that if there is an unexpected problem or error in the JavaScript it only affects the progress bar and the upload finishes and the page refreshes (bit of graceful degradation)  :-)

I'm assuming that ajaxSubmit is stopping the getJSON from working?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies to everyone and anyone that spent time reading this - I had left out a key hidden field in my form.  I worked through the whole thing again from start to finish and spotted it:

" value="upload" />